# Creating a curve using CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to create a template like [this one](https://www.odesk.com/info/howitworks/contractor/)  using CSS. I have created a div and used the following CSS code, which is looking like this-> http://jsfiddle.net/3kKkD/. But I don't know how to create the curve (I have pointed out in the image below)

Could you please show me how to do it?

Thanks

[image]

```
.container {
   width:75%;
   margin:0 auto; 
   margin-bottom:30px; 
   min-height:600px;
   background-color:#FFFFFF;
   -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #999;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #999;
   box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #999;
}

<div class="container">My Template</div>​
```

Comment: You can use an `:after` selector with display block, give it the same bg color as the orange and a border radius then just position it to sit where the curve should go :)

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks. I have tried this code `.container:after {

display;block;
background-color:#F78E1E;
border-radius: 10px;
}` But its not working. :(

Comment: It needs content: ""; and height and width dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please check this link http://jsfiddle.net/3kKkD/5/ . I have managed to display a box, but cannot make it look like the template of the website I have mentioned above. Could you please help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use border-radius.

```
border-radius: 10px;
```

Here is a decent guide

http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Using border-radius: 10px; is not solving my problem. It is just making the corners a bit round shaped.

Comment: Isn't the rebounded corners on the top menus what you were referring to? Or am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a css border radius generator

http://border-radius.com/

```
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS property you're looking for is "border-radius".

```
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
```

Read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp) to know more about this property.